# How to show html tags in a div element

Tags: html

I want to place some tag in a div element, i do not want them to be executed by browser like normal tags, for example i want to show exactly span tags in div element like this:

```
<div> //this is my div
<span> some text </span> // i want these span tags like a normal text in div element
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) your brackets so that they render as regular characters:

```
&lt;span&gt; some text &lt;/span&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the encoded version of the character >.

In other words, when the browser renders a page and it comes across the character < and > it assumes that it is HTML and begins to render markup. Since you want to display the tags and not render markup, you need to use the actual characters:

```
&gt; equals >
```

and

```
&lt; equals <
```

Most CMS systems will do this for you so you can see the code used as an example.

Comment: Basalloi used your way and for > it worked correctly but for < it does not work
i do not know why...

Comment: If you're closing the tag you have to do both so that <span> looks like &lt;span&gt; and </span> looks like &lt;/span&gt;